# Angular routing within child module (Feature) possible without importing the child module to the parent module (App)?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application that is comprised of a few different child modules that I would describe as "mini apps" that mostly keep to themselves.  In the "mini-app" modules, I would prefer them to have their own routing typescript files defined(so I can utilize the url path) but also be able to navigate to other "mini-app" modules (just to their default landing pages pretty much).  One key thing however is I don't want to import these modules in my app.module because that defeats the purpose of having them be modules that can lazy load only the necessary modules and components in the first place, however please correct me if I am misunderstanding this.

By default, I go from my main app module to my home module like this:

```
//app-routing.module.ts (parent routing file)

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }, // Redirect to Home module
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'dealer', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dealer/dealer.module').then(m => m.DealerModule) }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then in my "home" module define my routes and the default path:

```
//home-routing.module.ts (child routing file)

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { MarketplaceComponent } from './components/marketplace/marketplace.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'marketplace', component: MarketplaceComponent },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Inside HomeComponent where it defaults to, I have my <router-outlet> element for my navigation within the home module but this is where I'm getting confused.  I want the HomeComponent to be pure and just have the <router-outlet> tag with the child app pages coming in based of the local home routing.  To get the page I want to come up first, I set up the HomeComponent's *ngOnit like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['welcome']); 
  }
}
```

Somehow this was somewhat working for a bit but navigation from that page wasn't possible (unless navigating outside module) but now it's not even making it to the welcome page from home and the url stays as 'localhost:4200.'  And I get several warnings in the browser console that look like this:

```
Module "url" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "url.parse" in client code.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I would figure so since modules are allowed to have their own routing and children but I haven't been able to figure it out without importing it into the module to use the app routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just configure the routing to perform the redirect like so.

```
//home-routing.module.ts (child routing file)

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { MarketplaceComponent } from './components/marketplace/marketplace.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'marketplace', component: MarketplaceComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome' , pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

We can remove the `navigate` from home component since we have configured navigation through home child routing

Comment: Sadly didn't work for me after adding the redirect path and removing the *ngOnInit function from the home component.  Anything I should look for in my module.ts files?  Here's the error I'm getting in my console if it helps:

Comment: app-routing.module.ts:6 ERROR ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Mime.define (mime.js:25:7)
    at node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js (mime.js:87:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=b6be3d1b:41:50)
    at node_modules/send/index.js (index.js:24:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=b6be3d1b:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (utils.js:20:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=b6be3d1b:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:24:19)